# NetSuite REST API with Postman: Record not found while using Suiteql

Tags: postman, netsuite, suiteql

I'm trying to query some records like vendor and customer using suiteql with REST API using Postman.
The issue is that it return everytime the same error:

> "Invalid search query. Detailed unprocessed description follows. Search error occurred: Record 'customer' was not found."

[image]

I tried:

- differents syntax like Customer, CUSTOMER, customers, Customers, CUSTOMERS
  but no change.
- I added customer access to the role.

Is there something to activate while using suiteql with rest api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetSuite doesn't say it but for a record to be searchable, the user needs to have the following permissions:

Transactions:

- Find Transaction
- All the records needed

Lists:

- Perform search
- All the records needed

Setup:

- REST WEB Services
- Log in using Access Tokens or Oauth 2.0

Reports:

- SuiteAnalytics WorkBook

Answer (score 0):

Can you first try with select * from customer and see if any results are returned and then go on appending your conditions like date created greater than this year start

Comment: I tried and still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id, companyname, email, datecreated
FROM customer
WHERE datecreated >= BUILTIN.RELATIVE_RANGES('TFY', 'START')
AND datecreated <= BUILTIN.RELATIVE_RANGES('TFY', 'END');
```